# Empty Value Error when converting string to datetime object

Tags: pandas, string, datetime, python-datetime, valueerror

I am trying to convert a string containing time elements into a datetime object.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt

def converttime(dataset):
    for i in range(len(dataset)):
        datecol=dataset.loc[i]["Date"]
        date=datecol[:25]
        print(date)
        date=dt.strptime(date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
        dataset.loc[i]['Date']=date
    return dataset
```

The data is in this format:
'Mon, 14 May 2001 16:39:00 -0700 (PDT)'

I keep getting value error and I don't know why. the red first line shows the original formatting of the string and the second red line shows the string in the format i want. I don't know why the loop stops only after 2 iterations.

[image]

and this is the error I get when I call my function:

[image]

I don't understand what the error is.. or how to fix it...

Please help!!

Comment: **Add code, errors, and data as text**, not screenshots because [SO Discourages Screenshots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/). It is likely the question will be down-voted and closed. You are discouraging assistance because no one wants to retype your data or code, and screenshots are often illegible. [edit] the question and **add text**.

Answer (score 0):

there was an extra empty space at the end of my string splice. so i just used the strip function and now the function works:

```
def converttime(dataset):
for i in range(len(dataset)):
    datecol=dataset.loc[i]["Date"]
    date=datecol[:25]
    date=date.strip()
    date=dt.strptime(date, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
    dataset.loc[i]['Date']=date
return dataset
```